# Why didn't Terach go to the Land of Canaan?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, historical-figures, geography, parashat-noach, abraham

In [Genesis 11:31](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0111.htm#31), Terach takes Avraham (then Avram), Sarah (then Sarai), and Lot to the Land of Canaan, i.e. Israel. However, they stopped in Charan, and Terach spent the rest of his life there. Why didn't they continue?

Comment: Are you interested in an original thought, or do you only want a sourced answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Alshich - last piece on Parshas Noach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40267&st=&pgnum=71&hilite=) says that Terach never made it to Eretz Yisrael since he did not leave Ur Kasdim for the love of Eretz Yisrael, he left it as he was on the run. However Avraham who left Ur Kasdim as he had a love for Eretz Yisrael was rewarded that he arrived there.

Comment: implying Abraham knew about Israel before Lech Lecha?

Comment: How does he understand the words ללכת ארצה כנען - _to go to the Land of Canaan_?

Comment: @Ypnypn, that is where he was intending to go when he left Ur Kasdim, but he never made it there.

Comment: @Yishai But why not?

Comment: @Ypnypn, It doesn't say black and white, but my understanding is that he was running away, the danger passed, so he stopped. But the Alshich's point is that the way you get to Eretz Yisroel is by wanting it for its own sake, not by wanting to get away from something else (the Alshich is all about the Drash).

Answer (score 0):

Terach had **lacked in belief** as his son Charan did who died in Ur Kasdim in the fiery furnace; thus, he died in Charan. Neither of those two believed the holy revelation that was given to Avraham Avinu. The two seemingly were temporarily vouchsafed benefits by Avraham Avinu's merits for a time and to a certain point. However, **going to Eretz Israel is matter of conviction rather than simply convenience**. The furnace in Ur Kasdim was Charan's test for his passage to Eretz Israel and he failed. Charan was Terach's testing point prior to entry in Eretz Israel but he too failed miserably.

Comment: Welcome to MY and thanks for your first answer. MY likes it if statements can be backed up by evidence (e.g. from pesukim or commentaries) so that their  credibility can be enhanced. I would particularly like to see sources for what you write after the word, "However".